# You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets

Tags: powershell, activebatch

I have powershell script that connects to the Msol service .When i tried to run the script it works locally(powershell commandline Vscode) but when i try to run script via Active batch it is giving me error "You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets" .

```
 $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
 $EXOCred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("",$secpasswd) 
 $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $EXOCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
 Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber
 $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
 $MSOCred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("",$secpasswd) 
 Connect-MsolService -Credential $MSOCred
 $RoleObject = Get-MsolRole | Where-Object{$_.Name -match $roles}
 $members= Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $RoleObject.ObjectId
```

Can anyone help as i am getting error when executing the script in Active Batch

Comment: Your credentials are using the local interactive username. If you run in batch you must supply complete credentials. Credential objects are not portable either.
You can troubleshoot this kind of thing much better if you use Try..Catch and logging using Start-Transcript/Stop-Transcript

Comment: i have verified that the credentials are working fine. The problem relies within the connect-msolservice cmmdlet

Comment: Then add transcript/logging to find out why